# why we need to specify param and transaction in comment before a function in hyperledger composer?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

In hyperledger composer, we have to specify param and transaction in comments, isn`t compiler suppose to ignore comments? How does this work and why is it necessary to do that in comments?

```
/**
  * A temperature reading has been received for a shipment
  * @param {org.acme.shipping.perishable.TemperatureReading} 
    temperatureReading - the TemperatureReading transaction
  * @transaction
*/
    function temperatureReading(temperatureReading) {

var shipment = temperatureReading.shipment;

console.log('Adding temperature ' + temperatureReading.centigrade + ' to shipment ' + shipment.$identifier);

if (shipment.temperatureReadings) {
    shipment.temperatureReadings.push(temperatureReading);
} else {
    shipment.temperatureReadings = [temperatureReading];
}

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.shipping.perishable.Shipment')
    .then(function (shipmentRegistry) {
        // add the temp reading to the shipment
        return shipmentRegistry.update(shipment);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See here for more explanation -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html

Decorators within 'comments' are used to annotate the functions with metadata required for runtime processing. A Decorator is an object which adds functionality to another object dynamically, and not uncommon in Javascript.